# Installing pstoedit via macports is failing

Tags: macos, macports, octave

I'm in the process of installing **octave** through macports (which btw was a huge pain in the afternoon), after it compiled for nearly a day, macports is installing some last dependencies, one of them is **pstoedit**.

But the installation fails, because the repository seems broken. Installing it manually through macports with *-v* flag yields following output.

```
--->  Computing dependencies for pstoedit.
--->  Verifying checksums for pstoedit
--->  Checksumming pstoedit-3.70.tar.gz
Error: org.macports.checksum for port pstoedit returned: pstoedit-3.70.tar.gz does not exist in /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/pstoedit
Warning: targets not executed for pstoedit: org.macports.activate org.macports.checksum org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
Please see the log file for port pstoedit for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_pstoedit/pstoedit/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port pstoedit failed
```

Here is the [complete output](http://pastebin.com/5hh8nNUf), but it doesn't really contain more related info.

What can I do to satisfy octave's dependencies? Can the problem with pstoedit be solved? Would it be sufficient for macports, if I compile and install pstoedit myself, or are there any requirements on the side of macports?

Answer (score 1):

I also have pstoedit installed as a consequence of the MacPorts installation of Octave and I had similar problems today with building pstoedit 3.70_3 (when doing a "sudo port upgrade outdated") and found success with temporarily renaming /usr/local to /usr/local-temp

This temporary renaming of /usr/local can be seen as a suggestion in various places such as https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#usrlocal

What worked for me was:

```
sudo port clean --all pstoedit
sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local-temp
sudo port install --unrequested pstoedit
sudo mv /usr/local-temp /usr/local
```

The --unrequested flag was used since pstoedit is not something I need by itself, but only as dependant for some of my requested ports (namely Octave).

Probably we should report somewhere that this was necessary.

It is possible that the same effect could have been accomplished by using the "-t" flag as referenced in the FAQ linked above, but I did not try that.

```
sudo port -t install --unrequested pstoedit
```